# Unable to select multiple files in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm unable to select multiple files using tkinter's `askopenfilenames` on linux. I can select multiple files on windows but not on linux.

```
path = list(askopenfilenames(filetypes=('Images','*.jpg *.jpeg *.png')))
```

Comment: I have imported it already from filedialog: `from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilenames`

Comment: in python3 it already return list no need to add list constructor

Comment: Traceback? Error message?

Comment: No traceback or error. I can only select one file

Comment: @Mayank I used the line of code that you provided here as it is, along with a simple callback function and a button on Windows. When I click the button to open the file dialog, I get the error: `_tkinter.TclError: bad file type "Images", should be "typeName {extension ?extensions ...?} ?{macType ?macTypes ...?}?"`. If I update the line like this: `path = list(askopenfilenames(filetypes=[('Images','*.jpg *.jpeg *.png')]))` everything works. Show your working code here, show exactly how you use the file dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will allow you to select multiple files. You need to hold Control or Shift as you select each file

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

path = list(filedialog.askopenfilenames(filetypes=[('Images','*.jpg *.jpeg *.png')]))
print(path)
```

Comment: Had to hold shift. Sorry, I'm a bit new to linux.